# Executing a stored procedure by picking SQL variable from a list in T-SQL without using Cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-loop, variables, stored-procedures

I have a list of values, and i need the variable to pick it up one by one and execute the commands below. I need to achieve something like below in T-SQL. Is it possible without cursors?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @IPA VARCHAR(10)

FOR @IPA IN ['ADV, 'AC','AHA','ALPEB','AG','APCWEB]
    
IF OBJECT_ID('[ESProcess].[dbo].[EJ_Test]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [ESProcess].[dbo].[EJ_Test]
    
CREATE TABLE [ESProcess].[dbo].[EJ_Test]
(
    [PRIM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CLAIM_ID] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [P_CLAIMNO] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Pro] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [VALUE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [DESCRIP] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [FILENAME] [varchar](300) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [ESProcess].[dbo].[EJ_Test]
    SELECT 
        PRIM,a.CLAIM_ID,P_CLAIMNO, Pro, u.VALUE,
        NULL AS ErrorCode, NULL AS DESCRIP, [FILENAME] 
    FROM
        [SPID].[@IPA].[dbo].837_in_1 a
    JOIN
        [SPID].[@IPA].[dbo].[837_In_U] u ON a.ED_ID = u.M_ID
    WHERE
        a.CREATEDATE >= '20221001' 
        AND u.FNO = '20' 
        AND Pro = 'D'
END
```

Comment: You need to run a cursor with dynamic sql. Also, use quotename(@IPA) to safeguard against injection.

Comment: Thank you for your response, yeah, i want an alternative to cursor, since the data is huge and there are many tables involved, this is just a sample

Comment: There are no alternatives. Cursors are rightfully avoided as much as possible, but drawing things from multiple tables just cannot be done any other way.

Comment: Nothing wrong with cursors for control flow.  You just want to avoid them if it leads to row by row data retrieval.  Your cursor will construct a query that will then run against all rows so this is an ok use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here. Note that drop-creating the table means that at the end you will only have data from APCWEB.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @IPA VARCHAR(10)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

create table #ipas
(
     ord int
    ,ipa varchar(10)
)
insert #ipas(ord,ipa) values
     (1,'ADV')
    ,(2,'AC')
    ,(3,'AHA')
    ,(4,'ALPEB')
    ,(5,'AG')
    ,(6,'APCWEB')
    
declare ipa_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
    select ipa from #ipas order by ord

open ipa_cursor
while 1=1
begin
    fetch next from ipa_cursor into @IPA
    if @@fetch_status<>0 break
    
    set @sql=N''+
'IF OBJECT_ID(''[ESProcess].[dbo].[EJ_Test]'') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [ESProcess].[dbo].[EJ_Test]
    
CREATE TABLE [ESProcess].[dbo].[EJ_Test]
(
    [PRIM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CLAIM_ID] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [P_CLAIMNO] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Pro] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [VALUE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [int] NULL,
    [DESCRIP] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [FILENAME] [varchar](300) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [ESProcess].[dbo].[EJ_Test]
    SELECT 
        PRIM,a.CLAIM_ID,P_CLAIMNO, Pro, u.VALUE,
        NULL AS ErrorCode, NULL AS DESCRIP, [FILENAME] 
    FROM
        [SPID].'+quotename(@IPA)+'.[dbo].837_in_1 a
    JOIN
        [SPID].'+quotename(@IPA)+'.[dbo].[837_In_U] u ON a.ED_ID = u.M_ID
    WHERE
        a.CREATEDATE >= ''20221001'' 
        AND u.FNO = ''20'' 
        AND Pro = ''D'''
        
    exec sp_executesql @sql 
    
end -- cursor while
close ipa_cursor
deallocate ipa_cursor
```